# Why is KeyWindow.AddSubview causing this native crash

Tags: xamarin

I'm trying to show a loading view via the Xamarin `DependencyService`. The idea I'm using is to pass a `ContentPage` to a service which is platform specific and registered via the `DependencyService`. However, while things work as intended on Android, on iOS, I get some really strange behaviour.

This is the bit causing the native crash:

```
public void ShowLoadingPage()
{
    UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.AddSubview(_nativeView);
}
```

`_nativeView` is the `NativeView` of the renderer created from the XF `ContentPage` passed in.

On some pages where I call `ShowLoadingPage()`, I get an overlay that has a solid white (completely opaque) background, even though the `ContentPage` is meant to be a clear overlay.

And on this particular page where the crash occurs, it's not shown at all.

Here's the crash:

```
MyApp.iOS[12354:641574] critical: Stacktrace:

MyApp.iOS[12354:641574] critical:   at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
MyApp.iOS[12354:641574] critical:   at (wrapper managed-to-native) Foundation.NSObject.xamarin_release_managed_ref (intptr,Foundation.NSObject) [0x00008] in <0b60c1467e7449608ac42f9c7bbfdd05>:0
MyApp.iOS[12354:641574] critical:   at Foundation.NSObject.ReleaseManagedRef () [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.12.0.4/src/Xamarin.iOS/Foundation/NSObject2.cs:221
MyApp.iOS[12354:641574] critical:   at Foundation.NSObject/NSObject_Disposer.Drain (Foundation.NSObject) [0x00054] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.12.0.4/src/Xamarin.iOS/Foundation/NSObject2.cs:803
MyApp.iOS[12354:641574] critical:   at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_void_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x00051] in <0b60c1467e7449608ac42f9c7bbfdd05>:0
MyApp.iOS[12354:641574] critical:   at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
MyApp.iOS[12354:641574] critical:   at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr) [0x0005c] in <0b60c1467e7449608ac42f9c7bbfdd05>:0
MyApp.iOS[12354:641574] critical:   at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (string[],intptr,intptr) [0x00005] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.12.0.4/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:79
MyApp.iOS[12354:641574] critical:   at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (string[],string,string) [0x0002c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.12.0.4/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:63
MyApp.iOS[12354:641574] critical:   at MyApp.iOS.Application.Main (string[]) [0x00001] in /MyApp/XamarinApp/iOS/Main.cs:12
MyApp.iOS[12354:641574] critical:   at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_void_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x00051] in <eb83f305fed14faeaac09db08c7720da>:0
MyApp.iOS[12354:641574] critical: 
Native stacktrace:

MyApp.iOS[12354:641574] critical:   0   MyApp.iOS                   0x0000000101b07324 mono_handle_native_crash + 244
MyApp.iOS[12354:641574] critical:   1   MyApp.iOS                   0x0000000101b15600 mono_sigsegv_signal_handler + 288
MyApp.iOS[12354:641574] critical:   2   libsystem_platform.dylib    0x0000000109441f5a _sigtramp + 26
MyApp.iOS[12354:641574] critical:   3   libsystem_malloc.dylib      0x00000001091be98b free_tiny + 392
MyApp.iOS[12354:641574] critical:   4   libobjc.A.dylib             0x0000000107e276a7 class_getInstanceMethod + 53
MyApp.iOS[12354:641574] critical:   5   MyApp.iOS                   0x0000000101cce6e4 _ZL12is_user_typeP11objc_object + 36
MyApp.iOS[12354:641574] critical:   6   MyApp.iOS                   0x0000000101ccd6f9 xamarin_release_managed_ref + 25
MyApp.iOS[12354:641574] critical:   7   ???                         0x00000001295861ed 0x0 + 4988625389
MyApp.iOS[12354:641574] critical:   8   ???                         0x000000012a0ceb79 0x0 + 5000457081
MyApp.iOS[12354:641574] critical:   9   MyApp.iOS                   0x0000000101b18683 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 1443
MyApp.iOS[12354:641574] critical:   10  MyApp.iOS                   0x0000000101bee0ff mono_runtime_invoke_checked + 127
MyApp.iOS[12354:641574] critical:   11  MyApp.iOS                   0x0000000101bf181c mono_runtime_invoke + 76
MyApp.iOS[12354:641574] critical:   12  MyApp.iOS                   0x0000000101cd5cf2 xamarin_invoke_trampoline + 6018
MyApp.iOS[12354:641574] critical:   13  MyApp.iOS                   0x0000000101cdc7dd xamarin_arch_trampoline + 189
MyApp.iOS[12354:641574] critical:   14  MyApp.iOS                   0x0000000101cddc11 xamarin_x86_64_common_trampoline + 110
MyApp.iOS[12354:641574] critical:   15  Foundation                  0x0000000105ab6d5e __NSThreadPerformPerform + 330
MyApp.iOS[12354:641574] critical:   16  CoreFoundation              0x000000010700dbb1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
MyApp.iOS[12354:641574] critical:   17  CoreFoundation              0x0000000106ff24af __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 271
MyApp.iOS[12354:641574] critical:   18  CoreFoundation              0x0000000106ff1a6f __CFRunLoopRun + 1263
MyApp.iOS[12354:641574] critical:   19  CoreFoundation              0x0000000106ff130b CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 635
MyApp.iOS[12354:641574] critical:   20  GraphicsServices            0x000000010bf64a73 GSEventRunModal + 62
MyApp.iOS[12354:641574] critical:   21  UIKit                       0x00000001038bb057 UIApplicationMain + 159
MyApp.iOS[12354:641574] critical:   22  ???                         0x0000000127b08b37 0x0 + 4960848695
MyApp.iOS[12354:641574] critical:   23  ???                         0x0000000127b08893 0x0 + 4960848019
MyApp.iOS[12354:641574] critical: 
=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================
```

Why might this be happening? Is there something that can be deciphered from the crash log?

Comment: Can you provide more detail in iOS DependencyService?Or you can use  UIApplication.SharedApplication.Window.AddSubview(_nativeView);

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Just updated the version of Xamarin.Forms from 2.3.x to 2.5.x.